# How to get value from php to html tag?

Tags: php, html, forms

My first HTML file has a form a with a radio button. I want the second file (which is PHP) to print a message about what they choose. With that message thought, I would like to have some text formating (size, color, etc.).

`file.html`:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="file.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="favorite" value="rbOne">
    <input type="radio" name="favorite" value="rbTwo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

`file.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{
        background-color:white;
    }
    p{
        color:white;
        font-size:50px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php $choice = $POST_['favorite']; ?>


<p align="center">Thanks for voting for <?php echo "$choice" ?>!!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the Submit button, it going to the `file.php` page, but it displays this:

```
Thanks for voting for !!
```

It makes `$choice` blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need PHP opening and closing tags:

```
<?php echo $choice;?>
```

Also, `$POST_['favorite']` should be `$_POST['favorite']`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. I changed it. But still gives me the same thing.

Comment: @RobAveryIV I see the tags, not the `echo`

Comment: I added the `echo` but still leaves it empty in the end.